# Manipulating Mesh Vertices in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry, geometry-nodes

Is there a way to control the rotation of mesh vertices in Geometry Nodes? For example, could I rotate a mesh's vertices 45 degrees around the Bounding Box Center as I would in Edit Mode if I were to do it manually? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can, using *Vector Rotate* node to rotate, and *Attribute Statistic* to calculate the bounding box center (unless you mean the origin, then simply use the default 0;0;0 values for rotation center):

[image]

Comment: That works! Thank you very much, Markus!