# How to rotate a vertex group with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertex-groups

As you can see in the image, it's possible to translate the position of a vertex group of an object with Geometry Nodes thanks to the *Selection* input of the `Set Position` node and the *Input Attribute Toggle* of the *Geometry Nodes* modifier:

[image]

How can I achieve the same with a (not existing) node like `Set Rotation`? Note that the rest of the mesh is adjusted too like in `Set Position`, like this:

[image]

Unfortunately the `Transform Geometry` node has no *Selection* input. I tried several attempts of separating the vertex group geometry and joining it afterwards, but that does not respect the connections between the separated parts (well, which makes sense...). The `Rotate Instances` node has a *Selection* input, but that doesn't do anything with vertex groups and gives me a warning I don't understand. The closest I get to can be seen in the right part of the following image, but now I'm left with reconstructing through bridging the two faces, which may be possible ([other question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227730/is-there-a-way-to-bridge-edge-loops-with-geometry-nodes)) but seems overkill to me.

[image]

I feel like I am overlooking something obvious, but how to get a straightforward vertex group only `Set Rotation`?

Comment: related: [What is the Center in Vector Rotate Node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/278367/60486), [Manipulating Mesh Vertices in Geometry Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/249100/60486)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady thanks for adding the links, very useful. I just couldn't wrap my head around how to apply that to a vertex group.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The node `Transform Geometry` changes the transformation of the geometry, but not individual elements. Since you want to change specific points of the geometry here, you would have to use the `Set Position` node, which however uses [Fields](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/fields.html) (processing multiple elements of a given attribute domain).

The solution could look something like this:

[image]

Use `Named Attribute` to use the vertex group. The node `Attribute Statistic` gives you the mean position of the points of this vertex group.

With `Vector Rotate` you rotate the selected points around this center.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Although (i think) i understand fields, i would not have been able to come up with that. Thanks for broadening my geometry nodes horizon!

Comment: @taiyo You're welcome! That's exactly what https://blender.stackexchange.com is for!